# Smartphone project on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, smartphone

My employer has recently asked me to start a smartphone project for a device running windows CE 6.5.

I know that visual studio 2008 has the smartphone template and vs 2010 does not, I currently have vs 2010 and I've been told to install vs 2008 for this project.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve so in vs 2010 or vs 2008 is the only way to write smartphone applications. If it is possible to do so in vs 2010 then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do smart device development in VS2010. Stick to VS2008 as it is mentioned on microsoft website

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx

> Visual Studio 2010 does not support mobile application development for
>   versions of Windows Phone prior to Windows Phone OS 7.0." on this
>   page.

VS2010 you can download a special version for Windows Phone 7 development only for Windows Mobile from before Phone 7 you need VS2008.